# Read data from custom clr profiler in managed code?

Tags: c#, visual-c++, c#-4.0, c++-cli, profiling

I've been reading up on custom clr profilers and IL-weaving with ICorProfilerCallback. I get the general idea, and found this nice article that helped me get a skeleton together to play with; http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15410/Creating-a-Custom-NET-Profiler

My question is; given that this runs within the CLR runtime, is it possible to expose the results back to managed code? i.e. instead of writing the results of my profiler to a file, or building a whole UI in native code, can I just expose a native .NET API in the same dll? Am I forced to use COM interop?

Mono.Cecil sounds like it manages to expose a managed api, but I can't make heads or tails of that source tree.. Would appreciate any pointers.. Extra points if someone's got a simple example I can rip apart..